# InAppBrowser does not close in IOS

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Trying to close the browser in IOS after it opened, but it is silently doing nothing. It works fine on android.

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

...

let browser = this.iab.create(url, '_system');

setTimeout(() => {
    browser.close();
}, 5000);
```

In the debugger, I can see that I have the close() function, but it is not closing the window...
I am confused, whether this is implemented in ios or not... based on the other posts.

UPDATE:

In the documentation it says:

> OSX Quirks At the moment the only supported target in OSX is _system.
>
> _blank and _self targets are not yet implemented and are ignored silently. Pull requests and patches to get these to work are greatly
>   appreciated.

Trying it on ionic.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `'_system'` you don't open inAppBrowser, you open Safari, and there is no way of closing Safari because once Safari is open you leave your app.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question. Does it mean, that closing will never work for IOS?

Comment: Your edit is about OSX, not about iOS, close should work when using `'_blank'` on iOS.

Comment: Surprisingly it is closing the browser with blank... :) thanks